# cannot run kubeadm init on centos

Tags: centos, kubernetes

I am trying to run kubeadm init on my centos 8 server and I am getting this error

```
I0609 09:51:54.527931 2575529 version.go:255] remote version is much newer: v1.27.2; falling back to: stable-1.23
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.23.17
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING FileExisting-tc]: tc not found in system path
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR FileExisting-conntrack]: conntrack not found in system path
    [ERROR DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd]: /var/lib/etcd is not empty
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

so as the error says, `tc` and `conntrack` are missing, i tried to install it and got the below error.

```
Centos_8.x_x86_64                                                                                 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'Centos-8.x':
  - Curl error (37): Couldn't read a file:// file for file:///root/os/repodata/repomd.xml [Couldn't open file /root/os/repodata/repomd.xml]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'Centos-8.x': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

Comment: This is probably down to the fact that [CentOS Linux 8 has reached EOL](https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/). Article explains that if you want to keep with CentoOS8 you'll need to change the repos to use **vault.centos.org** BUT there will be no further updates. Refer to similar [Community issue](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/22398/error-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo-baseos-appstream-centos-8), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried the above comment and the issue is resolved?

Comment: this is the error now ``` 
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'extras':
  - Status code: 404 for https://vault.centos.org/centos/8-stream/extras/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 18.161.216.69)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'extras': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

Comment: i had to change a couple of my repo files to point to the right ones, but this worked, thank you for the help

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved now and I have captured the suggestions as a response for greater visibility for community members,if any changes required you can edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not working due to the fact that [CentOS Linux 8 has reached EOL](https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/). As per the official article, the contents of the official repository of CentOS Linux 8 were removed from http://mirror.centos.org/ to http://vault.centos.org/, where it will be archived permanently since Centos Linux 8 will not be able to provide updates to the content after the EOL date.

**Workaround 1:** Refer to **Aaron Kili’s** article on [Tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/error-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo-appstream/)

To fix the error, open your terminal or login via ssh, and run the following commands to change the repo URL to point to vault.centos.org, from the official CentOS repos.

Here you can use the sed command to edit the required directives or parameters in the repo configuration files:

```
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

**Workaround 2 :** Refer to [Techglimpse](https://techglimpse.com/failed-metadata-repo-appstream-centos-8/) content written by Ramya Santhosh. Follow the below steps to resolve your issue:

Step 1: Go to the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory.

```
[root@autocontroller ~]# cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Step 2: Run the below commands

```
[root@autocontroller ~]# sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
[root@autocontroller ~]# sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

Step 3: Now run the yum update

```
[root@autocontroller ~]# yum update -y
```